# file handling using pickle

Tags: python

try.py:

```
import pickle

f=open('abc.dat','w')
x=[320,315,316]
y=pickle.load(f)
f.close()
f=open('abc.dat','w')
for i in x:
        y.append(i)
pickle.dump(y,f)
f.close()
```

use.py

```
import pickle
import os

os.system('try.py')
f=open('abc.dat', 'r')
print "abc.dat = "
x=pickle.load(f)
print x
print "end of abc.dat"
f.close();
y=x[:]
for z in x:
        y.remove(z)
        print "removing " + str(z)
        print str(y) + " and " + str(x)
        f=open('abc.dat', 'w')
        pickle.dump(y, f)
        f.close()
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\parin\new start\use.py", line 7, in <module>
    x=pickle.load(f)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 1370, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 858, in load
        dispatch[key](self)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 880, in load_eof
    raise EOFError
EOFError
```

Comment: Try simplifying your code instead of dumping it verbatim here (heck, you might even find the problem by accident ;) ).  As a rule of thumb, 15 lines are more than enough for most problems

Comment: the extra lines came in the process of debugging.

Answer (score 3):

The error is in `try.py`:

```
f=open('abc.dat','w')
y=pickle.load(f)
```

Note that the `'w'` mode resets the file to size 0 (i.e. deletes its content). Pass `'r'` or nothing at all to open `abc.dat` for reading.

Comment: i figured that. when i pass 'r' in try.py, the 1st parse gives error coz the file 'abc.dat' doesnot exist.

Comment: @parin well, in that case, 'w' wouldn't work either, since an empty file is not a valid pickle representation. Instead, catch the error and initialize the value of y.

Answer (score 1):

Example doesn't work for me. `try.py` fails when the file doesn't exist.

My big recommendation, though, is to look at using JSON instead of pickle, as you'll have more cross-platform flexibility and the interface is more flexible.

For example, use this to create a file of JSON lines:

```
import json,random

with open("data.txt","w") as f:
    for i in range(0,10):
        info = {"line":i,
                "random":random.random()}
        f.write(json.dumps(info)+"\n")
```

(Make `info` whatever you want, obviously.)

Then use this to read them:

```
import json

for line in open("data.txt"):
    data = json.loads(line)
    print("data:" + str(data))
```